# Rename and move file with Babel WebStorm filewatcher

Tags: webstorm, babeljs, file-watcher

I'm trying to move to WebStorm (which I'm currently evaluating as a ST3 replacement) the following gulp workflow:

- upon each file save
- transpile with babel
- inline sourcemaps
- rename file from file.es6.js to file.js
- move it from `src/` tree to `dist/` directory tree.

I've tried messing with it, for example:

```
--source-maps inline --stage 1 --out-dir dist/
```

gets me some results, but not renamed, and with `$FileNameWithoutExtension$` I don't even know how to look into, extract that `es6.` part and remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have `dist/file.js` generated for each of your `src/file.es6.js`, try the following file watcher settings:

```
Arguments: --source-maps inline --out-file $ProjectFileDir$/dist/$FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot$/$FileNameWithoutAllExtensions$.js $FilePath$
Working directory: $FileDir$
Output paths to refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/dist/$FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot$/$FileNameWithoutAllExtensions$.js
```

I'm, however, not sure why you need replacing Gulp with file watchers - why not proceeding with Gulp? It works perfectly well with WebStorm

Comment: Well, I still prefer Sublime Text 3 + gulp, but I wanted to switch to WebStorm because of the Node.js debugger - and then I was looking into having it do more, since it's so heavy-weight already.
But maybe you're right, I should just stay with gulp.

Off to try this thing now, though.